All of our http inline images are broken
Since StackExchange switched to https for everything (yay) all of our http inline images are broken (boo).
I've seen this twice in the last few days:

on https://bricks.stackexchange.com/posts/8481/revisions I submitted a fix for a question I answered
on https://bricks.stackexchange.com/posts/6840/revisions I fixed my own

So now I'm wondering:

how do we find these occurrences site wide?
how many of them are there?
how many images have we lost forever?


It looks like everything has been fixed (as far as I can tell from using this. It doesn't look like we've lost any images because they were all working before they were re-uploaded.

This is a known issue in the transition to HTTPS. This post has more information:
Help us fix broken images!
That post also includes a tool to identify and fix the broken images. I've fixed a few images. It doesn't look like we have too many, perhaps 30, so it shouldn't be too time consuming to fix them.

It looks like Charlie Harding beat me to cleaning these up.  :)

This tool is very useful, it looks like quite a few have already been cleaned up.
